# Find $CD$, and calculate the distance between $AB$ and the circle center.

Tags: geometry, circles

Let $AB$ and $CD$ be perpendicular strings in the circle $\Gamma$.
$E$ is their point of intersection.
It is given that:
$1) AB=11$
$2) DE=6$ 
$3)$ The distnace between the string $CD$ and the circle center is $3.5$.
Here is a drawing:
[image]

I need to find $CD$ and calculate the distance between $AB$ and the circle center.

## My attempt -

I said that $BE=x$, then $AE=11-x$ and I used the fact that: 
If in a circle two strings are cut, then the product of one string segment equals the product of the other string segments, to get $CE=\frac{AE\boldsymbol{\cdot} BE}{ED}=\frac{x(11-x)}{6}$
From here, by Pythagoras theorem, I got that : 
$AD=(11-x)^2+36$, and $BC=x^2+(\frac{x(11-x)}{6})^2=x^2(1+\frac{(11-x)^2}{6})$.
That's that. Can't think of anything else.
One more thing is that I'm not allowed to use trigonometry. I.e $\sin(x), \cos(x)$, and so forth.

Please help!

Comment: You've not used condition 3 yet right? So how can we put it into play? In particular, what can we say about $BE + 3.5$?

Comment: @CalvinLin I didn't use this condition because I thought it ahve to do with the second part of the question, but when you put it like that then $BE+3.5=\frac{AB}{2}$, which helps a lot. LOL. THANK YOU!

Comment: @CalvinLin Do you think I should close this question, or keep it as is?

Comment: Can you post your solution? (It's fine to self-answer a question, esp once you figured it out.)

Comment: You use the concept of "**power of a point with respect to a circle**" without mentionning it ...

Comment: @JeanMarie If you mean the $CE=\frac{AE\cdot BE}{DE}$, then I did mention it, right after :"I used the fact that"

Comment: It is precisely what I meant : you use the property CE.DE = AE.BE without mentionning the mathematical concept of power of a point behind it, but it is not an essential remark...

Comment: I just didn't know the name in English